# Split Given String using Regex

Tags: regex

I need to split the below string

```
Carlos Molina;#1294;#Mary Balicki;#354;#Pascal Saura;#1211;#Niko
```

into the below format:

```
Carlos Molina
Mary Balicki
Pascal Saura
Niko
```

Please provide proper regular expression to solve this problem.

Comment: And what have you tried? What language is it? Have you even searched for the huge number of similar posts here on SO?

Comment: I haven't tried any expression. Language C#.net

Answer (score 2):

```
/([^#;\d]+)/g
```

can work for this example

Working example : http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?31rph

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `(?<=^|#)([^#]+?)(?=(;#\d+)|($))`

Comment: won't much the first one... and will much the number in a separate group!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow digits to be inside of text (e.g. "hello2world"), then go with:

```
/(?:^|(?<=#))(?!\d+(?=;|$)).*?(?=;|$)/g
```

Test it [here](http://regexr.com?31rqu).